# Access Key Vault from local Service Fabric cluster with User Assigned Manged Identity(MSI)

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity

I want to access the Key Vault from my Service Fabric application via Managed Service Identity (MSI). I have enabled MSI on the virtual machine scale set in the Azure Portal and given it access to my Key Vault resource. This works like a charm up in the cloud. However, I am having problems with my local develop environment.

As far as I understand, I can grant myself access to the Key Vault and run az login in Azure CLI. Alas, this doesn't work when running the application in a local Service Fabric cluster.
I am using .net core 2.1 in service fabric and getting below mentioned exception.

Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException: DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.

- EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
- ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. No Managed Identity endpoint found.
- SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication failed: Persistence check failed. Inspect inner exception for details
- Visual Studio Token provider can't be accessed at C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local.IdentityService\AzureServiceAuth\tokenprovider.json
- VisualStudioCodeCredential authentication failed: A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.

Answer (score 1):

Services are likely running under the built-in 'NetworkService' account, which cannot access the CLI for credentials because it has run in your user session.

Try [creating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/app-service-msi-keyvault-dotnet/keyvault-msi-appservice-sample/) **machine level** environment variables to access the vault:

> - Create a service principal with a password. Follow steps here to create a service principal and grant it permissions to the Key Vault.
> - Set an environment variable named AzureServicesAuthConnectionString to RunAs=App;AppId=AppId;TenantId=TenantId;AppKey=Secret. You need to
>   replace AppId, TenantId, and Secret with actual values from step #1.
> - Run the application in your local development environment. No code change is required. AzureServiceTokenProvider will use this
>   environment variable and use the service principal to authenticate to
>   Azure AD.

Don't forget to restart, so the environment variables are added to all processes.

Answer (score 0):

As the [document](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity#defaultazurecredential) shows about `DefaultAzureCredential`, Environment and Managed Identity are deployed service authentication. Azure CLI needs to login with your Azure account via the `az login` command.

So, Environment and Managed Identity are appropriate for you. For example, Using the environment needs to set Environment Variables first, see [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity#environment-variables). Then you could create a secret client using the DefaultAzureCredential.

```
// Create a secret client using the DefaultAzureCredential
var client = new SecretClient(new Uri("https://myvault.azure.vaults.net/"), new DefaultAzureCredential());
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working with with local service fabric development by opening Services.msc on my local development machine and configuring the 'Service Fabric Host Service' to run as my local user account rather than the default local service.

Only then would `DefaultAzureCredential` work for picking up the Az CLI login.

Comment: I tried this and it did work however the fabric:/System/EventStoreService began showing an error so I'm guessing this is not officially supported.